# Github page redirects to custom domain

Tags: github, dns, github-pages, cloudflare

I have Github Pages Site setup at [doshisid.github.io](http://doshisid.github.io). But it gets redirected to [sid.sh](http://sid.sh). I have one another domain which points to the same GitHub page and it works fine ([doshisid.com](http://doshisid.com)). But the default domain provided by GitHub doesn't. I can't figure out how is the default domain getting redirected to a custom domain.

Answer (score -1):

whatever domain you want in there; inside the repo create a new file CNAME and then add the domain name like www.xyz.com .This will solve your problem probably.

Comment: I do have a CNAME file. It only helps requests from that domain access the GitHub page. But it shouldn't redirect the requests from Github's default domain to the custom domain. That's the issue.